# Referencing variables in nested arrays

Tags: arrays, variables, nested

I'm trying to reference the "suggested" variable within this nested array as it gets spit out of a for loop. $_SESSION["products"]->suggested, did not work. There are other questions like this on SO but the answers are hard to follow. The for loop is below.

```
array(1) {
  ["products"]=>
    array(1) {
    [0]=>
     array(9) {
     ["name"]=>
    string(20) "m10x1-5-001 IVB bolt"
    ["code"]=>
  string(11) "m10x1-5-001"
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["weight"]=>
  string(3) ".03"
  ["price"]=>
  string(5) "37.00"
  ["image"]=>
  string(80) "/images/ProductPhotosLR/m101-5-001/m10x1-5-001-S.jpg"
  ["description"]=>
  string(39) "This is a short description of my item."
  ["suggested"]=>
  string(18) "IVB-METRIC-INSTALL"
  ["suggestedtext"]=>
  string(80) "First time owners of ....."
  }
  }
}
```

The loop I'm trying to use: (every item in a cart session would have a suggested item attached potentially) for loop works fine, if statement is broken.

```
if(!empty($_SESSION["products"]->suggested)) {
echo '<div id="products-wrapper"><h1>Suggested Items</h1><div class="view-cart">';
echo '<table width="750" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="text-align:center;padding:5px;">';

        foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm)  
        {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$cart_itm['suggested'].' '.$cart_itm['suggestedtext'].'</td></tr>';
        }
echo '</table></div></div>';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can "chain" keys or indexes of nested arrays just like you would access properties of an object

```
$_SESSION["products"]["suggested"]
```

Should help you with your Problem